# referencing self within a block IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, closures, objective-c-blocks, self

I'm trying to implament a callback mechanism where I pass in a block to the init of a class, and after some work that class calls me back.  The block gets called and most everything works, except when I call anything on "self" within the block.  I get Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” unless I comment out any reference to self within the block.

Am I wrong to think that I can access self within the block?
any advice would be greatly appreciated.  This code is in a brand new "Universal app" and I'm currently working on the IPad portion, so running under the IPad simulator.

Some code:

```
__block LoginViewController *blockSelf = self;
    LoginAlertView *alert = [[LoginAlertView alloc] 
                         intWithPinPrompt:NO 
                         title:@"Mobile Login"
                         myCallback:^(LoginAlertView *v){
                             DLog(@"self %@", blockSelf);
                             NSString *u = v.userNameText;
                             NSString *p = v.passwordText;
                             NSString *i = v.pinText;
                             [self authenticateUser:u
                                           password:p
                                                pin:i];
                         }];
```

and here is the some code from the LoginAlertView

```
- (id) intWithPinPrompt:(BOOL)pinPromptEnabled title:(NSString*)aTitle myCallback:(loginClicked)aCallback{
if (self = [self initWithTitle:aTitle
                       message:nil 
                      delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
             otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil]) {
    hasPinPrompt = pinPromptEnabled;
    theCallback = aCallback;
}
return self;
}
```

and the callback call

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (theCallback) {
    theCallback(self);
}
}
```

I changed to following line of code

```
theCallback = aCallback;
```

to

```
theCallback = [aCallback copy];
```

which is presenting me with the following error

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x029c8c97 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0xbfffe560 in ?? ()
#2  0x00026f66 in -[LoginViewController show] (self=0x4a38450, _cmd=0x209c36c) at LoginViewController.m:18
#3  0x00026d3b in -[AuthenticatedViewController viewWillAppear:] (self=0x4c1fac0, _cmd=0x20b59ac, animated=0 '\0') at AuthenticatedViewController.m:17
```

one other thing, the definition of my block looks like this

```
typedef void(^loginClicked)(LoginAlertView*);
```

and the member variable is this

```
loginClicked theCallback;
```

also tried moving the declaration of the block up to a variable, and passing that in. this had the same results Anytime I use the "copy" on the bock I get the dreaded Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. I thought maybe this was a IOS3.2 thing, so I tried running it under the IPhone 4.0 simulator, same results. Is there possibly a compiler setting that needs to be made in order to "Copy" the block onto the heap? I'm using LLVM1.5

Answer (score 4):

First, what is `blockSelf` in your code?

Secondly, no, there is no reason why you can't use `self` and this is indicative of a bug in your code.

Specifically, you aren't copying the block.  Blocks start out on the stack.  Thus, when you say `theCallback = aCallback;`, you are storing a reference to an on-stack data structure.  As soon as the defining stack frame goes away, that structure is no longer valid.

Change `theCallback = aCallback;` to `theCallback = [aCallback copy];` (and add `[theCallback release];` to your `-dealloc` method).

Comment: thanks for your response bbum
I have a line of code just before the call to LoginAlert alloc that says
 __block LoginViewController *blockSelf = self;
I was trying to see if the problem was something to do with self not being mutable, and from what I read unless you use __block variables on the stack are only available as "Const" within the block.  I know self isn't defined on the stack, but I thought it was worth a shot.
When i add your line of code "the copy" to the init of the LoginAlertView I get the following
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: It is the block that starts on the stack and that is the issue.  Did you copy the block correctly (I had a mistake in my answer; copying theCallback and not aCallback)?

Comment: added as "answer" to get code formatting, and allow more then 500 chars